# Error message: "the input does not start with a magic number"

Tags: r, web-scraping, shiny, shinyapps

I am trying to take web scraped data and develop a shiny app for practice in R. I keep getting the error message:

> "Error in load(url("http://www.hockeycentral.co.uk/nhl/records/alltimegoal.php")) :
> the input does not start with a magic number compatible with loading from a connection"

Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

load(url("http://www.hockeycentral.co.uk/nhl/records/alltimegoal.php"))
read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes("table") %>%
    html_table()

# Define UI for application
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
```

Comment: did you try with the "rvest" library?

Comment: Hi, @vinsfontecilla Yes, I did and I still received the same error message.

Comment: `load` is almost certainly the incorrect function to use. `load()` is for using Rdata files, not HTML files. The call to `load()` should not be needed at all. You can remove that. Just set `url <- "http://www.hockeycentral.co.uk/nhl/records/alltimegoal.php"` and then use `read_html` as you have it

Comment: just do:  url <- "http://www.hockeycentral.co.uk/nhl/records/alltimegoal.php"